# BPMN - how to model db updates

Tags: modeling, bpmn, bpmn.io

I'm an intern and I use bpmn with swim lanes to model a solution. How can I represent a database update when a user completes a task.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're modeling:

- If you model a business process,  you'll focus on the business tasks and not on the technical implementation details.  So if you have a user task `maintain the vendor account`, the user may interact with a system that will at some moment update the database; but these implementation details are not useful to your model. They would only make the diagram more complex to read and distract the business users.
- If you model the technical solution, for example if you'd have a dedicated lane for interactions with the IT system,  you could model the database update explicitly.  Your tasks would probably correspond to exposed business functions provided by the software (e.g. user transactions, or API services). You could then connect the relevant tasks to a [data store](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/bpmn/how-to-use-data-objects-in-bpmn/) symbol

[image]

Here how the BPMN standard defines them:

> A DataStore provides a mechanism for Activities to retrieve or update stored information that will persist beyond the scope of the Process. The same DataStore can be visualized, through a Data Store Reference, in one or more places in the Process.